# DNS Resolver Speed Techniques

Tags: latency, anycast, domain-name-system

I recently received a reply to my concerns about some DNS servers being slower than others despite all servers being anycast:

> In practice, most resolvers won't be
>   impacted by the slower paths to some
>   of the name servers in the set. Most
>   resolvers employ various techniques to
>   provide fast lookups, such as
>   preferring name servers that were
>   previously seen to be faster, sending
>   simultaneous queries to multiple name
>   servers, or pre-fetching queries
>   before the TTL has expired.

I was not aware that resolvers used these techniques and I was unsuccessful at searching for more info about this.

1. Are there any names for these techniques?
2. Which resolvers employ which of these techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Unbound can prefetch almost-expired cache entries. If configured to do do, it does the following. If a client requests some name that is in the cache, but with less than 10% of its TTL left, then the client gets the answer immediately from cache, but unbound also sends a query upstream.

As for the other two techniques (caching response time and sending queries to multiple upstream servers), I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For server preferences based on latency look up "RTT banding".